# mouse and mousepad not working properly

Tags: mouse

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Samsung Q35

The mouse pad has stopped working, only the buttons work.
The external mouse is also behaving very oddly, the mouse pointer works, but the button is not working properly, it has to be pressed many times or held down to select anything, and when anything that I select behaves as though the mouse is being clicked all the screen, settings will keep changing, the page will scroll, sliders will move up and down, tabs will toggle etc, so everything is unusable with the mouse, cannot even use the browser as it keeps scrolling the page up and down.

I have tested the mouse on another computer, and it works fine.

Please bear in mind that I am also a complete Linux novice, I installed Ubuntu on an old laptop for my kids, that is the limit of my experience.